# response.authResponse is null

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

i have write following code to check the login status of facebook.

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;  
    var page_id = "app_id"; 
    var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
    var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);
    the_query.wait(function(rows) {
                 if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                    alert("liked the page");
                 }
                 else {
                    alert("not liked ");
                 }
            });
  }
  else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

  }
  else
  {
    alert("not logged in");
  }
});
```

i am getting the value for `response.authResponse` in first if section i.e. in `if (response.status === 'connected') {}` part but i'm getting `response.authResponse`  null in `else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {}` part,

do anyone have any idea about it??

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to call the graph to get likes, you will need to have the user add/authenticate your app with the `user_likes` permissions and then you can read it.  So in your code above, when they fall into either of the two `else` cases, call FB.login() (or display the fb login button on the page).

If you don't want to force the user to add/authenticate your app, then you will need to configure your app as a Page Tab app and then you can grab the signed_request (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) and decode that providing access to know if the user has liked the page that your app is a page tab of.

Answer (score 1):

The authResponse object is null if you're not connected... since you're haven't authorized this seems logical ...

Comment: what exactly I want is, any user who visit my FB page is served with one popup, and that popup disappear only when he click on like button, i have done this, but it is working only with one FB user one which is admin of this page, for all other user it returns 'not_authorized' status